# In Chrome 18Dev+. Html5 canvas 'createPattern' can't draw the image right

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

This problem only happen in Chrome 18Dev+.Version 17 don't.
The area where should be the pattern is filled with black color.

Here's the code, you can copy it and run it in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>clock</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas{
            display:block;
            width:400px;
            height:400px;
            border:2px solid #000;
            margin:100px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='c'></canvas>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pic = new Image();
        $(function(){
            $(pic).load(function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
                canvas.width = 400;
                canvas.height = 400;

                if (canvas.getContext) {
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(pic, 'repeat');


                    setInterval(function() {
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        ctx.arc(canvas.width*0.5, canvas.height*0.5, 165, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
                        ctx.fill();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        });
        pic.src = 'https://www.google.com.hk/images/nav_logo105.png';
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I know this one.

[I reported it back in January, its still broken in Chrome Dev](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112165). See the last comment there.

It turns out that the pattern will work the first time its drawn in a tab. Then you have to *close the tab and make a new one* for it to work again. Refreshing the page won't do it. It's a real pain.